# Adding a Button below a ListView in a ListActivity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listactivity

I need a ListActivity with a ListView that has a Button below it. So you can scroll the ListView while the Button stays on the bottom. It looks fine in the layout but when i launch the app, there is no Button.
That is the XML of my ListActivity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:context=".PalettenActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPaletten"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonPalettenBetaetigen"
        android:entries="@layout/paletten_item"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenBetaetigen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Bestätigen" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the code of the paletten_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutPalettenItem"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".ChecklistAdapter" >
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPalettenBez"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Bezeichnung"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonPalettenPlus"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenMinus"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewPalettenAnzahl"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how i add the onClickListener to the Button in the onCreate() method of the ListActivity:

```
LayoutInflater itemInflater (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View convertView = itemInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_paletten, null);

btnPalettenBestaetigen = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonPalettenBetaetigen);
btnPalettenBestaetigen.setText("Bestätigen");
btnPalettenBestaetigen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btnPalettenBestaetigen.setEnabled(true);
btnPalettenBestaetigen.setClickable(true);
btnPalettenBestaetigen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                // do stuff
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    });
```

Here is my layout with the button visible:
[Layout of my ListActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak7VW.png)

Why isn`t the Button visible when i launch the app?
I am glad for any help!

Greetings
Morris F.

Answer (score 1):

SirGrey was right in the end.

> That must be a problem with your code... But i can't see the issue, if the activity shows nothing, must be something with with the inflater... – SirGery

The Problem was the Inflater so i did the following changes to my code:

- I deleted `android:entries="@layout/paletten_item"` from the XML of my MainActivity
- The MainActivity now `extends Activity` and no more `ListActivity`
- I `setContentView()` in my `onCreate()` method of my MainActivity
- I get the ListView by doing `listViewPaletten = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPaletten);`
- and I dont use the Infalter anymore.

Thanks a lot for your Help!

Comment: Didn't you have on your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`? i thought u have it.
Im glad i could "help" you solve the issue in some way!

Comment: No thats why i called it ListActivity :D

Comment: I had a mindbreak with your problem and you didn't even have that extend... :´)
Anyways issue it's solved so we're good!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll your `ListView` meanwhile the button stays in same position, try to use `FloatingActionButton`, it must solve your issue

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewPaletten"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:entries="@layout/paletten_item"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

</ListView>
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fActionButton"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,VectorDrawableCompat"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!
That didnt work out for me because my IDE doesn`t know FloatingActionButton and that leads to an error when i compile the app

Comment: Which android version are you running on your app @MorrisF?

Comment: Try to add this implementation into your `build.gradle`'s dependencies


`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` if that one doesnt work, try with the following ones 
   `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'`
   `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'`
   `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'`

Comment: I know it`s sad... But i need to tell you that i am using Android 18 with Eclipse Kepler as IDE... so i dont have a build.gradle file in my project. I know Android Studio is way better but the app i am programming is very large and very old in some parts. I tryed to migrate it into Android Studio but failed several times... So i have to go with Kepler...

Answer (score 0):

Then try this, swap the activity that makes reference, cause this is from my project

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activities.MainActivities.CartActivity">





<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewPaletten"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonPalettenBetaetigen">



</ListView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonPalettenBetaetigen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Bestätigen" />
```

Comment: I tried everything you said but nothing changes at all...?
When i set android:layout_height="match_parent" the whole layout-page is filled with the button but when i launch the app, there´s just my ListView without the button. 
I honestly don´t get it

Comment: It should work like this... tried in one of my projects and worked..., i have edited code above with full layout, try with it.

Comment: The layout looks fine now
But again: when i launch the app there's no Button below my ListView

Comment: That must be a problem with your code... But i can't see the issue, if the activity shows nothing, must be something with with the inflater...